# Sql Query Group a range of numbers with low's and high's

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks something like below

```
street_id | address_number | address_direction | address_street | address_type ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 121            | W                 | Fake           | St
1         | 131            | W                 | Fake           | St
1         | 200            | W                 | Fake           | St
2         | 321            | N                 | Fake           | St
2         | 131            | N                 | Fake           | St
2         | 500            | N                 | Fake           | St
```

Can anyone help me come up with a query that would help me display the data like below?

```
street_id | address_low_range | address_high_range | address_direction | address_street | address_type ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |  121              | 200                | W                 | Fake           | St
2         |  131              | 500                | N                 | Fake           | St
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Min(address_number) and Max(address_number) to select the low and high ranges, then group by street_id, address_direction, address_street, address_type:

```
SELECT 
street_id, 
Min(address_number) as address_low_range,
Max(address_number) as address_high_range,
address_direction, 
address_street, 
address_type
FROM table_name
GROUP BY street_id, address_direction, address_street, address_type
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
       street_id,
       direction,
       min(address_number) as address_low_range,
       max(address_number) as address_high_range
       address_street,
       address_type
from mytable
group by address_id, address_street, direction;
```

By the way, why are address_street and address_type in your table when assumably, that's what street_id refers to?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
select street_id, min(address_number), max(address_number), address_direction
from addresses
group by street_id, address_direction
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you test this query

```
    select street_id, MIN(address_number) add_low,
MAX(address_number) add_high FROM your_table
Group by street_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate functions on the columns you want the min or max of.  Make sure to include the other columns in a `GROUP BY` clause.